# Using QMI interface for SIM7600-H 4G module in Debian Bullseye

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, networkmanager, debian-bullseye

I am quite new to this, so be patient with me.

I want to establish a connection via LTE over a SIM7600-H 4G module. The module is built in an IPC, so I have no choice but using this module.

On the IPC I have an freshly installed Debian Bullseye without graphical UI. The connection should be established via ModemManager and NetworkManager. A SIM is connected to the IPC.
Moreover, on the IPC I have docker running hosting some containers needed. This will become important later.

As a matter of fact the connection cannot be established.
When in call `nmcli c` I have the following output:

```
NAME                         UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
Kabelgebundene Verbindung 3  2f8476a6-71fc-3e3b-9906-eac78a8a3715  ethernet  enx00e04f82b8c1
br-46836c0ad94d              e7ddf6ba-ca01-4fc8-86c3-c40f2c35e431  bridge    br-46836c0ad94d
eth1                         af45033b-1d1c-4f29-831f-d01620119260  ethernet  enp1s0
docker0                      1284ebb4-010e-4658-bbe0-7e2188298dd4  bridge    docker0
eth0                         0b607d47-d313-449b-8911-7a307c2552a4  ethernet  enp0s31f6
hotspot                      c819c76e-c604-4fe4-8484-49a87d8af472  wifi      --
Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1  b84a613f-6ea8-3cb6-8f21-280dd2028a01  ethernet  --
Kabelgebundene Verbindung 2  f3e8dd43-0887-3020-947b-a14413a2c9fa  ethernet  --
lte0                         eaf626d7-c115-4061-97e9-7b26b612c047  gsm       --
```

So as you can see the modem is not connected.
Calling `mmcli -m 0` has the following output:

```
 -----------------------------------
  General  |               dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
           |               device id: 6e46feda3e60a1419f0bb5413eb212813cf841d0
  -----------------------------------
  Hardware |            manufacturer: QUALCOMM INCORPORATED
           |                   model: 0
           |       firmware revision: LE11B12SIM7600M22
           |          carrier config: Commercial-DT
           | carrier config revision: 05011F11
           |            h/w revision: 10000
           |               supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |                 current: gsm-umts, lte
           |            equipment id: 867584033521118
  -----------------------------------
  System   |                  device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5
           |                 drivers: option1, qmi_wwan
           |                  plugin: simtech
           |            primary port: cdc-wdm1
           |                   ports: cdc-wdm1 (qmi), ttyUSB0 (qcdm), ttyUSB1 (gps),
           |                          ttyUSB2 (at), ttyUSB3 (at), ttyUSB4 (audio), wwan0 (net)
  -----------------------------------
  Status   |                    lock: sim-pin2
           |          unlock retries: sim-pin (3), sim-puk (10), sim-pin2 (3), sim-puk2 (10)
           |                   state: registered
           |             power state: on
           |             access tech: gsm
           |          signal quality: 39% (recent)
  -----------------------------------
```

The connection is in state "registered", but not "connected".

What have I tried:

I blacklisted the QMI driver. That made the LTE work. BUT: The docker container could not start afterwards. This is as I found out because of the following bug in dockerd: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43034

So, my goal is now to achieve that I get the connection over the QMI interfac as this seems to work with docker as well.

Some more info:
The ouput of `more syslog | grep tty` is:

```
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and logind are not available being skipped.
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    0.075765] printk: console [tty0] enabled
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    0.944470] 00:03: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    0.946315] 00:04: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    0.948215] 00:05: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 11, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    0.950137] 00:06: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 10, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    3.538417] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    3.538587] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    3.538834] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    3.539442] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    3.539599] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
Nov 30 09:52:02 tt-factory systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Nov 30 09:53:49 tt-factory lte-device-watchdog[453]: Device on /dev/ttyUSB3 found, sending reset command
Nov 30 09:54:52 tt-factory lte-device-watchdog[453]: Device on /dev/ttyUSB3 found, sending reset command
Nov 30 09:55:55 tt-factory lte-device-watchdog[453]: Device on /dev/ttyUSB3 found, sending reset command
Nov 30 09:56:58 tt-factory lte-device-watchdog[453]: Device on /dev/ttyUSB3 found, sending reset command
Nov 30 09:58:01 tt-factory lte-device-watchdog[453]: Device on /dev/ttyUSB3 found, sending reset command
```

The output of `more syslog | grep qmi` is:

```
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    3.621485] qmi_wwan 1-5:1.5: cdc-wdm1: USB WDM device
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    3.624587] qmi_wwan 1-5:1.5 wwan0: register 'qmi_wwan' at usb-0000:00:14.0-5, WWAN/QMI device, ba:5b:51:b1:ff:aa
Nov 30 09:51:50 tt-factory kernel: [    3.624630] usbcore: registered new interface driver qmi_wwan
Nov 30 09:51:52 tt-factory ModemManager[477]: spawning new qmi-proxy (try 1)...
Nov 30 09:51:53 tt-factory ModemManager[477]: [/dev/cdc-wdm1] Reading expected data format from: /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip
Nov 30 09:51:53 tt-factory ModemManager[477]: [/dev/cdc-wdm1] Writing expected data format to: /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip
Nov 30 09:51:53 tt-factory ModemManager[477]: [/dev/cdc-wdm1] Reading expected data format from: /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip
```

I am quite stuck here. So any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.